# How to make a variable which assigns numbers based on a variable?

Tags: r

For example, I am trying to make a variable that will assign `1, 2, 3,4.`

1 `<25th percentile`

2 `>= 25th percentile` upto 50th percentile

similarly, 3 and 4. and so on

Could anyone give me some clues in how I would complete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `breaks` as `quantile` in `cut` and then convert the `factor` output to `integer` with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(cut(v1, breaks = quantile(v1)))
```

Comment: Oh, wow! That worked. Thanks so much. Sorry for my bad grammar and terribly asked question. I wrote it with too much gusto.